# MYSQL Query not working as it should

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
$sql = "UPDATE `shows` SET `title` = '$title', `tagline` = '$tagline', `desc` = '$desc' , `img_src = '$imgsrc' WHERE id = $showid";
```

The query above does not want to work, I simply get a mysql_error saying error at '' on line 1;

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Please tell me you've [properly escaped your SQL values](http://bobby-tables.com/) because code like this is usually dangerously insecure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a tick:

```
   `img_src = '$imgsrc' WHERE id = $showid";
```

should be:

```
   `img_src` = '$imgsrc' WHERE id = $showid";
```

Comment: Haha. That's an understatement. Perhaps some motivation would help too.

Comment: No worries. We've all been there. :)